# Populating entity field type in dynamic form Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, symfony

I have an entity Lexeme, which contains Language and Phoneme entities.

In my Form Type, I want the Phoneme choices to be different depending on the Language entity chosen for the Lexeme.

The problem is when I dynamically update the form, the correct Phonemes are displayed, but they are not populated from the database: i.e. those Phonemes which belong to the Lexeme in the database do not appear as checked in the dynamically loaded form.

The Lexeme Controller:

```
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $lexeme = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme')
        ->find($id);
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme')
        ->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->where('l.id > :thisId')
        ->setParameter('thisId', $id)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();
    $nextLexeme = $query->getResult();
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme')
        ->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->where('l.id < :thisId')
        ->setParameter('thisId', $id)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();
    $previousLexeme = $query->getResult();
    if ( count($nextLexeme) < 1 ) {
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme')
            ->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->orderBy('l.id', 'asc')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery();
        $nextLexeme = $query->getResult();
    }
    if ( count($previousLexeme) < 1 ) {
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme')
            ->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->orderBy('l.id', 'desc')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery();
        $previousLexeme = $query->getResult();
    }

    if (!$lexeme) {
        $lexeme = new Lexeme();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new EditLexemeType(), $lexeme);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($lexeme);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('aleph2_omega_transcription_lexemes_edit', array ('id'=>$lexeme->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Lexeme:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'previousId' => $previousLexeme[0]->getId(),
        'nextId' => $nextLexeme[0]->getId()
    ));
}
```

The Lexeme Form Type:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $language) {
        $form
            ->remove('phonemes')
            ->add('phonemes', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Phoneme',
                'property' => 'latin',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($language) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->select('p')
                        ->from('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Phoneme', 'p')
                        ->where('p.language = :language')
                        ->setParameter('language', $language);
                },
            ));
    };

    $builder
        ->add('language', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Language',
            'property' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        ))
        ->add('defaultGreek')
        ->add('defaultHebrew')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        //->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->add('words', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new WordLimitedProtoType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'options' => array('data_class' => 'Aleph2Omega\TranscriptionBundle\Entity\Word'),
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
        ->add('phonemes', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Phoneme',
                'property' => 'latin',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->select('p')
                        ->from('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Phoneme', 'p')
                        ->where('p.language = :language')
                        ->setParameter('language', '1');
                },
            ))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function ($event) {
                $event->stopPropagation();
            },
            900)
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if ($data instanceof Word) {
                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getLanguage());
                }
            }
        )
        ->get('language')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $language = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $language);
    });
}
```

The Lexeme Twig template:

```
    {{ include('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle::menu.html.twig')  }}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    <h1><a href="{{ path('aleph2_omega_transcription_lexemes_edit', {'id': previousId}) }}">&#60;</a> Edit Lexeme <a href="{{ path('aleph2_omega_transcription_lexemes_edit', {'id': nextId}) }}">&#62;</a></h1>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <table>
        <tr><th>Language</th><td>{{ form_widget(form.language) }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Default Greek</th><td>{{ form_widget(form.defaultGreek) }}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Default Hebrew</th><td>{{ form_widget(form.defaultHebrew) }}</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Phonemes</th></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ form_widget(form.phonemes) }}</td></tr>
    </table>

    <h3>{{ form_widget(form.save) }}</h3>

    <table class="words" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Word:limited_prototype.html.twig' with { 'item': form.words.vars.prototype } %}{% endfilter %}">
        {# iterate over each existing word and render its fields #}
        <tr><th>transcription</th><th>normalised</th><th>Hebrew</th><th>comment</th></tr>
        {% for word in form.words %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(word.transcription) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(word.normalisedTranscription) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(word.hebrewTranscription) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(word.comment) }}</td>
        </tr>
        {{ form_rest(word) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The javascript for AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$("[id$=language]").change(function() {
    languageChange();
});

function languageChange() {
    var $languages = $("[id$=language]");
    $($languages).each(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'), //Routing.generate('route_id', /* your params */), //
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                    $phonemes = $("[id$=phonemes]");
                    $($phonemes).each(function() {
                        $(this).replaceWith(
                            $(html).find('#'+this.id)
                        );
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

languageChange();

});
```

**UPDATE: Some screenshots**

In private correspondence, some people wanted clarification as to the behaviour I'm looking for.

Here's a page from a different entity (word), which doesn't make use of AJAX to populate the phonemes field. This exhibits the sort of behaviour I would like:
[image: A different entity that doesn't rely on AJAX, displaying the desired behaviour]

The Lexeme entity (which the code above is for), which is updated via AJAX, correctly displays the right phonemes for each language, it's just that the phonemes recorded in the database as "connected" to the Lexeme are not checked.

E.g., here are the correctly displayed phonemes when "Hebrew" is selected:

[image: Partially correct behaviour of the AJAX dependent Lexeme entity displaying Hebrew phonemes]

And here are the correctly displayed phonemes when "Greek" is selected:

[image: Partially correct behaviour of the AJAX dependent Lexeme entity displaying Greek phonemes]

Finally, as far as debugging goes, I've rooted around using Chrome console and network display, and this hints that the problem may be due to CSRF with AJAX. However, what I don't understand is—if CSRF really is the problem, why is the page returned from the server at all?

[image: An attempt to debug: a CSRF problem in Chrome's Network communication with the server—relevant??]

**UPDATE 2: A partial work-around**

Ok, so a partial workaround to at least get the initial page-load displaying correctly is to avoid the AJAX call. This doesn't solve the problem of ensuring that AJAX updates display everything correctly, but at least improves functionality (and is, I think, a better-practice way of pre-populating the form anyway than using AJAX).

In the buildForm function, the data to populate the form can be obtained by using:

```
$lexemeEntity = $builder->getData();
```

This can then be fed into the initial query populating the phonemes entity type (note, don't forget to "use" this in the declaration of the defined function):

```
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($lexemeEntity) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->select('p')
                        ->from('Aleph2OmegaTranscriptionBundle:Phoneme', 'p')
                        ->where('p.language = :language')
                        ->setParameter('language', $lexemeEntity->getLanguage());
                },
```

Finally, the default AJAX call on the initial load of every page needs to be turned off in the javascript. I did this by just commenting:

```
//languageChange();
```

Now initial page loads are all populated correctly—but further updates to the forms using AJAX are still not loaded with all the data, any help with this still very much welcome.